# SQL hangs when using SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: sql-server, distinct

SQL server hangs when I try to run a simple Select Distinct query from a linked table. "Executing Query. Waiting for response from data source." Then returns an error: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

```
SELECT DISTINCT UR_RISK_ID AS [Risk ID]
FROM         FWLIVE..LMDATA.UDS_RISK
```

Without the "distinct" it is fine and runs very quickly.

Any thoughts why?

Comment: what happens when you discard result sets :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386587/how-to-execute-sql-query-without-displaying-results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select distinct` is essentially the same as:

```
SELECT UR_RISK_ID AS [Risk ID]
FROM FWLIVE..LMDATA.UDS_RISK
GROUP BY UR_RISK_ID;
```

In other words, the engine has to do a lot of work to remove the duplicates.  I would suggest creating an index on `UDS_RISK(UR_RISK_ID)`, so the index can be used for the query.

I should also note that the `SELECT` can start returning rows as they are encountered.  The `SELECT DISTINCT` needs to process *all* the data before returning any rows.  If you have a unique id in the table, then there might be other options that returns some rows more quickly.

Comment: Will this do better `select * from (select row_number().. from ) a where rn = 1` just curious

Comment: I would expect `select distinct` to be faster because the engine would (probably) assign `rn` to each row and then do the filtering.  The `distinct` would just filter.  But, SQL Server might have optimizations so the two are essentially the same.